# How to search for a substring in a custom filter in ActiveAdmin?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, filter, activeadmin, ransack

In the past:

A model `User` has a string filed `first_name`. If I write `filter :first_name` in ActiveAdmin model it would display a drop-down besides the input field with the options `Contains`, `Equals`, `Starts with`, `Ends with`. So for examle if I choose `Contains` and write `ik`, it would find, for example Mike.

Now:

If I use a custom filter I just get a large input, spanning across two columns, which only does exact search. I define my filter like so:

1. Create a scope in the model.
2. Whitelist it with `ransackable_scopes`.
3. Add it to the admin model like so: `filter :my_filter, as: :string`.

How do I get the functionality to seach for substrings?

Answer (score 0):

To search for substrings you must use the [Ransack Search Predicate Syntax](https://github.com/activerecord-hackery/ransack/wiki/Basic-Searching) i.e. if you want search a substring on field `first_name` you must configure this way:

```
filter :first_name_cont, as: :string, label: "Name"
```

You can find more information [here](https://github.com/activeadmin/activeadmin/blob/master/docs/3-index-pages.md)

I hope it helps.

Comment: I think this will work pretty well if I try to search a column on a model. However, my case is a bit more complicated, I am using a custom filter, which uses a scope, as my search method, so I thinks the `contains` part must be defined somewhere earlier on, for example in the lambda of the scope.